# What model to pick when dependent variable has weak correlation with all features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation

I am performing EDA on a dataset. All the features and predictor are numerical features.
After dealing with missing data, the next step I did was to find the Pearson correlation between each feature and the output variable and I see that the absolute value of correlation for each feature is less than 0.4.

As per my understanding all features have weak correlation with predicted variable, is Linear regression still a good choice for such a dataset or what model should we choose when we see weak correlations? What is your recommendation?

[image]

Note: The last bar that shows correlation=1 is actually the predictor variable

Comment: I can't imagine there would possibly be a general rule in this case. You're considering each feature in isolation, then trying to make assumptions about the form of a model with access to all features.

Comment: This is correlation of each feature with predictor and please correct me If I am wrong I think its a necessary step to check the correlations with predictor to go further with a linear regresssor. What other steps would you recommend?